# Mono internationalization

Tags: c#, mono, internationalization, gettext, xgettext

I am following [this basic tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/internationalization/) for C# console app internationalization.
I am at the final step for displaying translated text which requires to input this command in mono console:

`LANGUAGE=es mono i18n.exe`
But the `LANGUAGE` command isn't recognized. Am I missing something, or is this command not intended for windows? Because it's funny, that the tutorial is for C#, but command lines there are for unix system. There are some other small mistakes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the LANGUAGE command isn't recognized

```
LANGUAGE=es mono i18n.exe
```

LANGUAGE in that context is an environment variable. In *nix shell environments that is a way to pass env. vars to a cmd without setting/exporting them first.

Under Windows that cmd would be:

```
SET LANGUAGE=es 
mono i18n.exe
SET LANGUAGE=
```